# Java Why the inheritance doesn''t work when there are 2 private constructors?

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose that I have two classes.

The first one is called "User1", and the second one is called "User2".

User2 inherits User1.

When I make the constructor of User1 private then the IDE gives error

> "There is no default constructor available in User1".

Why is that? Can anybody explain to me?

Comment: Private or static?  Your title and your question ask two different things.

Comment: You should go learn more about [Java Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: There is no such thing as a static constructor.  If you used the word `static` then you did not write a constructor, you wrote a method.

Comment: I meant "private" constructor. Sorry for that. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that is **marked** `static` belongs to the class only, for example `static` method **cannot be inherited** in the `sub class` because they belong to the class in which they have been declared. 
Since each `constructor` is being called by its subclass during creation of the object of its subclass, so if you mark `constructor` as `static` the `subclass` will not be able to access the constructor of its parent class because it is marked static and thus belong to the `class` only. This will **violate** the whole purpose of **inheritance** concept and that is reason why a **constructor cannot be static.**

If you are asking about a `private` `constructor` the answer is  you **can't** extend the Parent class if it has a **private  constructor**. You have to make the constructor available to the subclass. In this case you need to have a default constructor that have a **protected or public or default** access modifier.

Comment: *"private default constructor"* ... rubbish, there is no such thing as a private default constructor.